# what rights should be given for my live asp.net sql server?

Tags: sql-server, rights

I am wondering what rights should be given to sql server user for asp.net website considering following criteria

Sql server user

**Should be able to do**

- read from tables
- insert into tables
- update rows
- execute sp, udf

**Should NOT be able to**

- delete any of the tables
- delete any records from table
- delete any stored proc, udf or any other procedures
- create new table
- create new sp, udf, trigger, index etc
- alter any table
- alter any columns in tables
- alter any sp, udf, trigger, index etc
- any other dangerous stuff

Comment: Your list already defines the rights you want to give, so have you reviewed the documentation on permissions in SQL Server - especially the GRANT command - and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a user and then apply the following scripts substituting USERNAME with your sql user. This will generate all the scripts you should need!

```
  --STORED PROCS
    select  'GRANT EXECUTE ON [' + sys.schemas.name + '].[' + sys.objects.name +'] TO USERNAME' as SQL from sys.objects
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON sys.schemas.schema_id = sys.objects.schema_id
    where type = 'P' 

--TABLES
select  'GRANT SELECT ON [' + sys.schemas.name + '].[' + sys.objects.name +'] TO USERNAME' as SQL from sys.objects
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON sys.schemas.schema_id = sys.objects.schema_id
where   type = 'U'

--TABLES
select  'GRANT INSERT ON [' + sys.schemas.name + '].[' + sys.objects.name +'] TO USERNAME' as SQL from sys.objects
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON sys.schemas.schema_id = sys.objects.schema_id
where   type = 'U'


--TABLES
select  'GRANT UPDATE ON [' + sys.schemas.name + '].[' + sys.objects.name +'] TO USERNAME' as SQL from sys.objects
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON sys.schemas.schema_id = sys.objects.schema_id
where   type = 'U'


--FUNCTIONS
select  'GRANT EXECUTE ON [' + sys.schemas.name + '].[' + sys.objects.name +'] TO USERNAME' as SQL from sys.objects
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON sys.schemas.schema_id = sys.objects.schema_id
where  type = 'FN'


 --VIEWS
  select 'GRANT SELECT ON [' + sys.schemas.name + '].[' + sys.objects.name +'] TO dardsfp' as SQL from sys.objects
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON sys.schemas.schema_id = sys.objects.schema_id
where  type ='V'
```